# How do i select rows based on specific condition

Tags: sql, r

I am trying to select specific rows based on specific condition. Like to get values all below z with respect to 1st column and exclude the ones on top. I tried using filter and group by but it is not working Input and expected output provided below

```
Input    
abc  x  
abc  y   
abc  z  
abc  g  
abc  t     
pqr  x  
pqr  z  
pqr  y  
cvb  z  
cvb  x  
cvb  y
```

Expected Output

```
abc  g  
abc  t  
pqr  y  
cvb  x  
cvb  y
```

Comment: Can you please share the expected output? Kindly share your data using `dput` so that we can directly work.

Comment: the one where i have written 'output' is the expected output which i am trying to achieve

Comment: Could you please share your input dataset using `dput`?

Comment: Input data is the one i have provided in the image.. i dont know how to share the input dataset. Really sorry as i dont post here frequently

Comment: it would be a great help if u could suggest a solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution via `dplyr`,

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(a) %>% 
 mutate(new = row_number()) %>% 
 filter(new > new[b == 'z']) %>% 
 select(-new)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 2
> # Groups:   a [3]
>    a     b    
>  <chr> <chr>
> 1 a     g    
> 2 a     t    
> 3 b     y    
> 4 c     x    
> 5 c     y
> ```

**DATA:**

```
structure(list(a = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", 
"c", "c", "c"), b = c("x", "y", "z", "g", "t", "x", "z", "y", 
"z", "x", "y")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```